# php echo not working with html in it

Tags: php, html

I want my php to print something when the user submits.this is the error I get:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'javascript' (T_STRING),
>   expecting ',' or ';' in
>   /homepages/31/d585123241/htdocs/test/xe5/form.php on line 9

This is my code, what can I do to fix it:

```
<?php
echo "$ret bytes written to file<a href ="javascript:history.go(-1)">go back</a>";
```

Comment: can't you just escape it

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use single quotes inside the string

```
echo "$ret bytes written to file<a href ='javascript:history.go(-1)'>go back</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the string in single quotes instead.

```
echo $ret.' bytes written to file<a href ="javascript:history.go(-1)">go back</a>';
```

UPDATE:

There are multiple ways to solve this:

1. Use single quotes inside the string per @SQL hacks answer
2. Wrap the string in singe quotes as originally shown in this answer.  This requires concatenation of PHP variables.
3. Escape the double quotes inside the string 
   `echo "$ret bytes written to file<a href =\"javascript:history.go(-1)\">go back</a>";`

I'm sure other solutions are possible but the most valuable approach would be to learn about PHP strings and string operations/functions in general.  A good starting point would be here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php